# Rails 3.2.6; rake 0.9.2.2; db:migrate aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm new to Rails, and am following the getting started guide on their website.

I'm getting an error when I run `$ rake db:migrate` in section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-model

It worked for the first time in section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#running-a-migration

So I don't know what is wrong.

When I run `$ rake db:migrate`

```
==  CreateComments: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:comments)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007f83a27503c8>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I followed the instructions to run it with the `--trace` argument; I was wondering if anyone has a clue what it means, and what the issue is?

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
==  CreateComments: migrating =================================================
-- create_table(:comments)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

private method `test' called for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition:0x007f8bacbba730>
/Users/parnmatt/Sites/test-rails/blog/db/migrate/20120627130542_create_comments.rb:5:in `block in change'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:160:in `create_table'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:466:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:438:in `say_with_time'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:458:in `method_missing'
/Users/parnmatt/Sites/test-rails/blog/db/migrate/20120627130542_create_comments.rb:3:in `change'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:280:in `measure'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:407:in `block in migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:123:in `with_connection'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:389:in `migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:528:in `migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:720:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `call'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:775:in `ddl_transaction'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:719:in `block in migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `each'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:700:in `migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:570:in `up'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/migration.rb:551:in `migrate'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.6/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:153:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/parnmatt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

This is the migration code generated:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.test :body
      t.references :post

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, :post_id
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the migration code? It looks like there's an issue in the create_comments migration.

Comment: @MatthewLehner — edited the post to include the generated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like when you ran the generator you said 'test' instead of 'text' for body.

Should have been: $ rails generate model Comment commenter:string body:text post:references

Rake doesn't know what type t.test is...it would have been t.text